Ansible playbook in Oracle Linux Automation Manager logs output only after task completion instead of in real-time
I'm running an Ansible playbook through Oracle Linux Automation Manager to stop WebLogic, but I'm encountering an issue with the logs. When I execute the shutdown script directly using the command

sh /home/oracle/wip/new/wls_stop.sh

, it outputs logs line by line in real-time. However, when I run the same script through my Ansible playbook, the logs are only displayed after the entire task completes, not in real-time.
Here's my playbook:
---
- name: Stop Weblogic
  hosts: "{{server}}"
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: awx
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml
    - "{{server}}.yml"
  tasks:
    - name: Run the weblogic shutdown command
      command: sudo su - oracle -c 'sh /home/oracle/wip/new/wls_stop.sh'
      register: shutdown_output
      become: true
    - name: Display weblogic shutdown output
      debug:
        msg: "the shutdown output is {{ shutdown_output.stdout }}"

I would like the logs to be displayed in real-time during the playbook execution. Does anyone know how to achieve this or if there's a setting in Oracle Linux Automation Manager that controls this behavior? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
